# Explicitly understanding the map representing first cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Let $M$ be a closed smooth manifold. It is well-known that there is a bijection between the cohomology group $H^n(M;G)$ and $[M,K(G,n)]$, where $G$ is a group and $K(G,n)$ is an Eilenberg-Maclane space. In particular there is a bijection between $H^1(M)$ and $[M,S^1]$, and I would like to concretely understand what this is.

In one direction, this is simple: $H^1(S^1)$ has a distinguished generator $u$ given by the identity map $\pi_1(S^1)\to\mathbb{Z}$, so given a map $f:M\to S^1$ we obtain $f^*u\in H^1(M)$ depending only on the homotopy class of $f$.

For the other direction, the way I have found it easiest to construct a map is as follows. We may think of $H^1(M)$ as the group of "integral de Rham classes" of closed 1-forms, which are those closed 1-forms $\alpha$ for which
$$\int_c\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}$$
for all smooth 1-cycles $c:S^1\to M$. Given such an integral 1-form we can define the period group
$$\Omega_{\alpha}=\left\{\int_c\alpha|c\in H_1(M)\right\}\subset\mathbb{Z}.$$
Now fix any $p\in M$ and notice that
$$q\mapsto\int_p^q\alpha$$
is well-defined as a map $M\to\mathbb{R}/\Omega_{\alpha}\cong S^1$. I call this map $\phi_{\alpha}$.

I now have two questions.

1. Is the above construction valid? The notion of integral 1-forms is a bit confusing to me.
2. If so, are the two assignments above inverses to one another? That is, do we have $[\alpha]=[\phi_{\alpha}^*u]$? If I'm not mistaken, this would mean that for every smooth $c:S^1\to M$ we'd have

$$\int_{S^1}c^*\alpha=\int_{S^1}(\phi_{\alpha}\circ c)^*u=\deg(\phi_{\alpha}\circ c).$$

Comment: Note that $\alpha\in H^1_{dR}$ is closed but not exact. The expression $\int_p^q\alpha$ is ambiguous because the integral depends on the path along which you're integrating. Also, de Rham cohomology is defined for smooth manifold, so your "inverse" construction assumes additional structures on $M$.

Comment: It is ambiguous, but only up to integration of $\alpha$ over a 1-cycle. If I have two paths $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ connecting $p$ to $q$, then $\int_{\gamma_1}\alpha-\int_{\gamma_2}\alpha=\int_{\gamma_1-\gamma_2}\alpha\in\Omega_{\alpha}$, since $\gamma_1-\gamma_2$ is a cycle. I am assuming throughout that $M$ is a closed smooth manifold, perhaps I should have been clearer on that